# Multiple distinct YAFNET forums (via different pages) on same site

Tags: asp.net, yaf, yetanotherforum

I have an existing YAFNET forum at http://www.paydirt.co.nz/forums/ concerned with Gold Fossicking and Metal Detecting. At present these two "Categories" are all grouped together on a single page.

Unfortunately from time to time I get a bit of bickering between the gold fanciers and the swingers so I'd like to separate these out across two distinct pages:
http://www.paydirt.co.nz/forums/gold (could end in .aspx if required)
http://www.paydirt.co.nz/forums/metal-detecting (could end in .aspx if required)

I'd like the users to be shared across both pages without users re-registering (as some users contribute to both areas), but the pages themselves I'd like to be be filtered by category. Each page would only show "Active Discussions" for the category used.

Is it possible to setup 2 distinct pages each with a YAFNET user control on, but using parameters on the user controls which will filter the categories shown on each?

I do see that it's possible to setup multiple "boards", and I could move some categories manually via an update to the database. However, I also notice that the `yaf_User` table has a `BoardID` so this would suggest users are tied to a single board.

As a bonus nice-to-have, I'd ideally like the "Discussion" category (which is a general discussions area for anything) to be shared between these two pages. Though I suspect this might be asking a little too much.

Thanks in advance for any ideas or solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YAF.NET always pulls users from the current Membership Provider. The yaf_User table is a sync from the Membership Provider. For example, when an existing membership user visits a new board, YAF.NET will automatically create an new entry in yaf_User for that user and keep them synced.

Multiple controls with different board setting should do what you need. They do require unique "Pages", though.